# How to replace null with " " double quotes for json output in php

Tags: php, json

I need help, we have already developed 500+ web-services for the current project, i don't want to modify all the web-services, can any help me how to replace null with " " double quotes for json output in php using output buffer..

**Actual Output came**

```
{
  "err_code": "valid",
  "title": "",
  "message": "User details",
  "data": {
    "fullname": "Vijay Kumarr",
    "mobile": "4564564564654",
    "token": "OGUBXtyxDARNISJGOlQu",
    "customer_meta": {
      "id": "6",
      "customers_id": "6",
      "email": "xyz@abc.com",
      "alternative_mobile": null,
      "door_no": "1-2/3",
      "street_name": "Street",
      "location_name": "Locationn",
      "city_name": "vizag",
      "district_name": "Vizag",
      "state_name": "Andhra Pradesh",
      "zipcode": "530016",
      "countries_id": "1",
      "gst_number": null,
      "aadhar_number": null,
      "pan_number": null,
      "created_at": "1522060789",
      "updated_at": "1522484859",
      "status": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

**I am expecting Output as**

```
{
  "err_code": "valid",
  "title": "",
  "message": "User details",
  "data": {
    "fullname": "Vijay Kumarr",
    "mobile": "4564564564654",
    "token": "OGUBXtyxDARNISJGOlQu",
    "customer_meta": {
      "id": "6",
      "customers_id": "6",
      "email": "xyz@abc.com",
      "alternative_mobile": "",
      "door_no": "1-2/3",
      "street_name": "Street",
      "location_name": "Locationn",
      "city_name": "vizag",
      "district_name": "Vizag",
      "state_name": "Andhra Pradesh",
      "zipcode": "530016",
      "countries_id": "1",
      "gst_number": "",
      "aadhar_number": "",
      "pan_number": "",
      "created_at": "1522060789",
      "updated_at": "1522484859",
      "status": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately your question boils down to *write code for me*, while many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input, expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). Check the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: What have you written to try to solve your problem? Where does the data come from?